# IE8 don't register blur event in a element - Using consumedEvents in a dataGrid

Tags: java, gwt, datagrid

Internet Explorer 8 doesn't execute the inputtextcells' blur events in a datagrid. It works in others browsers, including IE9/10. Can someone answer me?

Comment: you need to post the relevant code

Comment: answer you what? You didnt ask a question you made a statement.

Answer (score 1):

This is a known issue: http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/detail?id=7139

Answer (score 0):

The best workaround I can think is to add "OK" "Cancel" buttons to the editor, it does not look that bad and it works.
Easiest way to do this is to modify `com.google.gwt.cell.client.DatePickerCell`